# How can I multiply the text within columns by a specific number and then count the total?

Tags: excel

Here's the table I'm working with:

[image]

This is the analysis for a pokemon-type game. I counted the `mons` from a specific list. For example, there are 74 armordigoals. Armordigoal has two types: Iron and Rock.

My goal is to count the total number of types across all the `mons` I counted. By this I mean, 74 armordigoals means +74 Iron and +74 rock. 61 Alligwamp would mean +61 Insect and then +61 rock (bringing rock total to 135). I need to get a full total count for all the different types listed on the right.

I've been thinking I could use the REPT function somehow, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you illustrate your desired output in a column manually?

Comment: From what you explained and your data, it looks like you are just doing `Count * 2` and then a `SUM` below. But I'm afraid that's not what you need.

Comment: @Harun24HR The best way I could explain it would be =REPT(M4, L4)... that would repeat the word "Iron" 74 times. I would do it again for =REPT(N4,L4)... that would repeat the word "Rock" 74 times. So now the running total for both rock and iron is 74. I would then do that for each type in row M & N multiplied by the Count in corresponding row L and then sum the total for each type (i.e. how many times was "Rock" repeated.

Comment: @Andrew pls see my response to Harun above ^, that is the best explanation I could come up with

Comment: Do you want a cell to have `Rock Rock Rock Rock...`? Or in different cells? That looks quite weird. And why would you count the total if you already know that value (you know how many times you are repeating the word to begin with). Can you display how the end result would look like? (Just a few rows, not everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most efficient approach is to convert both tables into excel table and use `SUMPRODUCT` to avoid playing with ranges.

1. Convert the range with data into `tblData`
2. Convert the range with references into `tblRef`

And use this formula next to `Reference column`:

`=SUMPRODUCT((tblData[Type1]:tblData[Type2]=[@Reference])*(tblData[Count]))`

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try using dataframe in pandas , groupby sum and count will give all the stats you might looking for

```
df.groupby['Type 1'].sum()

df.groupby['Type 1'].count()
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your sample data display columns A:F, you would want the sum of B:B where C:C = F2 plus the sum if B:B where D:D = F2. That leads you to this formula.

```
=SUMIF($C$2:$C$80,F3,$B$2:$B$80)+SUMIF($D$2:$D$80,F3,$B$2:$B$80)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, this is probably what you want:

1. Extract all unique Type from [Type1] and [Type2] by combine 2 columns [Type1 and Type2] 
   (I have joined them by copying paste into column H) -> Click Tab Data -> Remove Dulicate
2. Calculate the sum corresponding to the values

The formula that I used:

> ```
>   I2=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$E$6=H2)*$C$2:$C$6)            'ctrl + shift + enter if not 
>
> or:
>
>   I2=SUMPRODUCT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE($C$2:$C$6),--($D$2:$E$6=H2)))
> ```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!